# Angular - Unable to guard to a route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to allow a user to browse a certain url based on the return value from an api.

This is the route:

```
{
path: 'request',
component: RequestLayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: JobCreateComponent,
    resolve: { canContinue: STResolver },
    canActivateChild: [LimitGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' 
  }]
}
```

This is the resolver:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class STResolver implements Resolve<any>{
constructor(private router: Router, private data: DataService, private inspectionService: InspectionService, private searchForm: SearchForm) {}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    this.searchForm.userId = this.data.localStorageFind()
    let search = this.searchForm
    search.sort = ESort.DESC
    this.inspectionService.getLimit(search).pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
            if (res.status == false) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        })
    );
    return
    }
}
```

This is the guard:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LimitGuard implements CanActivate {
canContinue: any

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.canContinue = this.route.snapshot.data.canContinue;
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.canContinue = this.route.snapshot.data.canContinue;
    if (this.canContinue == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/inspections/request']);
        return false;
    }
  } 
}
```

Everytime I attempt to browse the url `/request/create` it throws this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: invalid
Error: invalid
    at Module.lp (main.js:1:471005)
    at hn.children.resolve.canContinue.n.ɵfac [as factory] (798.js:1:107375)
    at Ph.hydrate (main.js:1:457363)
    at Ph.get (main.js:1:455928)
    at Ph.get (main.js:1:455976)
    at ci (main.js:1:631393)
    at mo (main.js:1:658002)
    at main.js:1:658073
    at ne (main.js:1:214335)
    at O (main.js:1:214272)
    at Pe (polyfills.js:1:140142)
    at Pe (polyfills.js:1:139642)
    at polyfills.js:1:141019
    at k.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:130653)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1:557682)
    at k.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:130574)
    at k.runTask (polyfills.js:1:125676)
    at pe (polyfills.js:1:1330
```

Earlier, I tried to make the api call in the Guard but that still gave the same error.  Is there anything particularly wrong with how I'm handling the promise value from the Observable or it's another issue?

Comment: Have you tried `canActivate: [LimitGuard]` instead? That route doesn't have any children for `canActivateChild: [LimitGuard]`

Comment: Yeah, I first tried `canActivate` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Add `canActivate` and `canActivateChild` to the parent route

Comment: Both? The parent component already has a guard.

Comment: You can have as many guards as you want on a route, that is why you give it an array.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to go about that. (Adding canactivate and canactivatechild)